Typescript not resolving types in async then-catch statement
I have the following code which is a simplified version of making an API call and handing the response.
type Result<TValue, TError> =
    | { ok: true, value: TValue}
    | { ok: false, msg: TError };

function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function testRequest(): Promise<{success: true, data: number} | {success: false, msg: string}> {
    await sleep(1);

    const roll = Math.random();

    if (roll > 0.3) {
        return { success: true, data: 123 };
    } else if (roll > 0.6) {
        return { success: false, msg: 'hello world' };
    } else {
        throw new Error('value to high');
    }
}

async function runner(): Promise<Result<number, string>>{
    return await testRequest()
        .then( res => {
            if (res.success) {
                return { ok: true, value: res.data }
            } else {
                return { ok: false, msg: res.msg }
            }
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error('testRequest failed', { error });
            return { ok: false, msg:'request failed'}
        })
}

The type checker returns an error on the return await testRequest() line:
Type '{ ok: boolean; value: number; msg?: undefined; } | { ok: boolean; msg: string; value?: undefined; } | { status: string; msg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Result<number, string>'.
  Type '{ ok: boolean; value: number; msg?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Result<number, string>'.
    Type '{ ok: boolean; value: number; msg?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ ok: false; msg: string; }'.
      Types of property 'ok' are incompatible.
        Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.

Result is a union of a success and failure object, each of which return a representative boolean status and an associated value or msg key.
The error message suggests that {ok: true, value: string} cannot be returned for type Result<number, string>. However the same pattern is used in testRequest with no issues?
What can I fix about runner() to make it work with a success|failure type?

Looks like a workaround is to write out the then and catch handlers as separate functions and type annotate them.

Nvm can add typing to the anonymous functions as well.

If it's an "nvm", just delete your comments =) (and if it's not, then that information should go in your post, not in a comment)

A simple solution is to return Result as const, because the object by default will have a property ok of type boolean instead of true or false :
.then( res => {
            if (res.success) {
                return { ok: true, value: res.data } as const
            } else {
                return { ok: false, msg: res.msg } as const
            }
})
// or
.then( res => {
            if (res.success) {
                return { ok: true as true, value: res.data } 
            } else {
                return { ok: false as false, msg: res.msg }
            }
})

if you want to avoid using type assertion (or const assertion), you can use res.success directly as your ok value:
.then( res => {
            if (res.success) {
                return { ok: res.success, value: res.data } 
            } else {
                return { ok: res.success, msg: res.msg }
            }
})


Yes but i already did that in the code.

Interestingly none of these worked for my actual code - but they do solve the problem as written.

my bad I missed that you did

That would be a problem, if by any chance you found the reason of the error, just ask a new question with more details.

I don't think as const counts as a "type assertion"

@Bergi it is basically a const assertion, i forgot to mention that, i edited the post to add it.

Another solution that doesn't involve assertions is to explicitly type the problematic arrow function:
async function runner(): Promise<Result<number, string>>{
    return await testRequest()
        .then( (res): Result<number, string> => {
            if (res.success) {
                return { ok: true, value: res.data }
            } else {
                return { ok: false, msg: res.msg }
            }
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error('testRequest failed', { error });
            return { ok: false, msg:'request failed'}
        });
}



using function abc(): ExplicitReturnType is a type assertion, you're asserting that the return type will be this type. try using satisfies instead. You can check this by removing the asserted return type from the runner function itself and use the following instead
runner() satisfies Promise<Result<number, string>>;
if all cases do not satisfy the type you've included it will provide details as to why

what is the goal of having a Result<TVal, TErr> generic? I'm asking because a more straightforward solution might be to use type inference.
I copy pasted the code you provided into the typescript playground
Then decided to snag a utility helper I wrote in recent months -- InferIt
if you hover over the inferred return types for the testRequest and runner functions (TestRequestInferred and RunnerInferred, respectively) you'll notice that it's a union of objects for either. Here is a screenshot of the TestRequestInferred type on hover

here is the code I came up with for your testing
// RT -> ReturnType
// P -> Params
// B -> { readonly params: P; readonly returnType: RT };

type InferIt<T, V extends "RT" | "P" | "B"> = T extends (
  ...args: infer P
) => infer RT | Promise<infer RT> | PromiseLike<infer RT> | Awaited<infer RT>
  ? V extends "B"
    ? { readonly params: P; readonly returnType: RT }
    : V extends "RT"
      ? RT
      : V extends "P"
        ? P
        : T
  : T;

function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function testRequest() {
  await sleep(1);

  const roll = Math.random();

  return (roll > 0.3 && roll <= 0.6)
    ? { success: false, data: 123 }
    : roll > 0.6
      ? { success: true, msg: "Hello World" }
      : (() => {
          throw new Error("value too high");
        })();
}

type TestRequestInferred = InferIt<typeof testRequest, "RT">;

async function runner() {
  return (testRequest() satisfies Promise<TestRequestInferred>)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.success === true) {
        return { ok: true, value: res.data };
      } else {
        return { ok: false, msg: res.msg };
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("testRequest failed", { error });
      return { ok: false, msg: "request failed" };
    });
}

testRequest().then((d) => {
    console.log(d);
    return d;
});

type RunnerInferred = InferIt<typeof runner, "RT">;


example

Here is a link to the playground containing the code
